# What is the formula of ESTIMATED dividend yield?

Tags: united-states, stocks, dividends

[image]

If you're going to say it's based on last 12 months of dividends: let's sum up the distributions of last 12 months and divide that by *which* stock price?

Stock price of the last day of the month?

Average stock price of of last 12 months?

If average, based on the average of last days of the months? Or is it a daily average of closing prices? Or is it something else?

Comment: why sum up the dsitributions,  and not average the yields?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the dividend yield and not the yield on the investment including dividend yield and price movements?

Answer (score 2):

Dividend yield is a function of the stock’s price. It is calculated by dividing the annual dividend payments divided by the stock’s current price. It changes every time share price changes.

You can massage the data any way that amuses you.  For example, if you were interested in the average daily yield for the year, you would average the 250+ daily yields.